# Grails and IntelliJ Cache Issues

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

we are using Grails together with Maven and Intellij. For the beginning of the project it worked everything nicely. Now we are getting more and more strange effects like when somebody is checking in wrong code, some are getting error some are not.

Are there any best practices to config IntelliJ so thats it working on each machine good and predictable?

We found out that some having the "make" before starting the project disabled but this didnt solved the issue.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You didn't specify the actual problem, so it would be hard to help you. If you've spotted a bug, file an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with the sample project attached and the steps to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got very little problems in 2 years. Idea had couple of cache issues a year ago, I wiped caches by hand. Ever since then, had no problems with caches/indexes.

Couple of things I could think of:

- `grails clean` usually fixes most weirdness;
- Yes, removing "`Before launch - make`" flag stops Idea from doing wrong guesses and unnecessary compilation (which id does differently from Groovy compiler);
- For every new run configuration, we add `ValueFormatter` to VM parameters, or add it to Grails defaults;
- Create a run configuration for `test-app` and run it on regular basis;
- Give it as much memory as you can in `idea.vmoptions`.

Comment: Thank you Victor, now we all are getting the same error msg: Type [null] is not a basic type or a domain class and cannot be mapped. Either specify a type within the [mapping] block or use a basic type (String, Integer etc.). Do you know where this is comming from? I googled already and its saying that grails doesnt like inner classes or enum's in gorms but I have nothing like that...

Comment: What's the source you get the error on? Does it happen when you run your app in command line with "grails run-app"?

Comment: No source is displayed at all. I did now a clean checkout from svn and now its working again with grails run-app. This was really strange..

Comment: I mean, can you identify the domain class causing this? Do you have domain classes with inheritance, or inner classes? You can exclude them one-by-one and finally identify the offending code.

Comment: No domain class is posted in the error msg. I already thought about excluding but the problem is I have around 49 domain classes which could take a lot of time :-)