# Intellij idea unresolved symbol in grails + gwt project

Tags: gwt, grails, intellij-idea

I have a grails project and I use the gwt plugin 0.6.1. GWT version is configured using ivy.

I have a strange unresolved symbol error when I try to use a class in package `com.google.web.*`. When I use the complete class names inline idea reports that it cannot resolve the `web` package. If I import the same class no error ocurres.

I already tried to run `grails clean` and removed the idea `system` directory as well - nothing works.
Idea usally import the class when I use smart complete but in this case idea insert the complete classname instead of importing the class.

The `web` package is found in the `gwt-users-2.4.0.jar` and `gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar`. Both jars are in the classpath but this how the grails gwt plugin organizes gwt dependency.

Error when using full inline claasnames:

[image: Error when using full inline claasnames]

No error when using same class in import statement:

[image: No error when using import]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It's a bug. I've created an issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-81056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed already http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-81056

Fix is included in the next IDEA 11.1 EAP
http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11.1+EAP

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issue with IntelliJ IDEA, I solved problem by invalidating the idea cache. After invalidating the cache it will reindex all your library and other files. check this answer as well. [Grails and IntelliJ Cache Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345638/grails-and-intellij-cache-issues) 
 
[image]

Comment: Did not work. Invalidate Caches, `grails clean` and removing ideas local system dir did not help. The problem stays the same.

Comment: what version of IDEA are you using?

Comment: A weird issue, maybe it's a real bug as Sergey mentioned.... If it worked with earlier releases try using it until it's fixed :(